# Intersection of open dense sets is dense

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A_n$ be open and dense subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ for each $n\in \mathbb N$. We need to prove that the intersection of all the $A_n$ is dense. (Note: we have not studied Baire Category Theorem)

I know that we can prove that a set $S$ is dense in some set $A$ if for every nonempty open set $U\subset A$, $U\cap S\neq\emptyset$. So my logic is that take some $U\subset A$, and prove $U\cap(A_1\cap(A_2\cap(...A_n)...)\neq\emptyset$ by using the fact that each of those sets is open and dense. Is this logic correct? If so how would I get this $U$?

Comment: What about this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/693899/intersection-of-open-dense-subsets-g-n-of-rk-n-1-2-is-not-empty-more ?

Comment: $\not=\emptyset$ perhaps?

Comment: I changed $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^k$ - right?

Comment: Also, reading the first sentence it looks like you have a countable number of sets, in the end it looks like $n$ is fixed.

Comment: I made an edit to the question

Comment: I'm confused, Does each R^n have only one corresponding A_n associated to it? If so, are The R^n embedded in their R^n+1s and then we want the final denseness condition in R?

Answer (score 2):

Let $W$ be nonempty open set.

Obviously we can define sets $V_n$ such $V_n \subset (\cap_{1 \le i \le n} A_i$) $\cap W$, $\overline{V_n}$ $\subset V_{n - 1}$ and $diam\ V_n \to 0$.

If $v_i \in V_i$ then $v_i$ is сauchy sequence.

So $\cap_{1 \le i \le \infty} V_i$ = $\{\lim v_i\}$ and $\cap_{1 \le i \le \infty} V_i$ $\subset (\cap_{1 \le i \le \infty} A_i$) $\cap W \ne \emptyset$.

Comment: I don't quite understand what $diam$ means and why $v_i$ is cauchy

Comment: Since we're in $\mathbb R^n$, it probably easiest to let $V_n$ be a closed ball; this saves some technical details where the sequence of radii tend to $0$. Then, for each $n$, all following centres will be inside $\overline V_n$, and so form a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: @SamM How is the cauchy sequence formed?

Comment: Choose an $n$ large enough so that the radius of the $n$-th ball is sufficiently small, the centres of all following ball will be inside this ball, and thus no more than twice the radius of the $n$-th ball apart.

Comment: @SamM How do we define the closed balls?

Comment: @SamM So that the radius of the $n$-th ball is sufficiently small?

Comment: Let $U$ be any open set in $\mathbb R^n$. Then, for each $x\in U$, there exists $r>0$ such that the closed ball $F$ (centre $x$ and radius $r$) such that $F\subseteq U$.

Comment: @SamM why does $r$ tend to $0$?

Comment: Choose them that way.