# Intersection of open dense subsets of $\Bbb R^k$ is not empty.

Tags: real-analysis

[Intersection of open dense subsets $G_n$ of $R^k$ $n = 1,2,\dots$ is not empty (more over its dense)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/693899/intersection-of-open-dense-subsets-g-n-of-rk-n-1-2-dots-is-not-empty)
I am interesting about the construction of $C_k$.

I think if I want to prove this problem, I will choose a point $x_1\in G_1$ and there is a neighborhood $V_1$ of $x_1$ contained in $G_1$ such that $\bar V_1\subset G_1$. (It is possible because $G_1$ is open, so there is $r>0$ such that $B(x_1,r)\subset G_1$ and $V_1\equiv\bar B(x_1,r-\varepsilon)\subset B(x_1,r)$ for some $\varepsilon$ is small.)

By induction, we have construct a sequence of compact set $\{\bar V_n\}$ such that:

1. $V_n\subset V_{n-1}\cap G_n\neq\emptyset$
2. $\bar V_n\subset V_{n-1}\cap G_n \Rightarrow\bar V_n\subset G_n$

Hence, $\{\bar V_n\}$ is a sequence of nonempty decreasing compact sets:

$V_{n+1}\subset\emptyset\neq V_n\cap G_{n+1}\subset V_n\subset\bar V_{n}$

So, by the finite intersection property, $\cap \bar V_n\neq \emptyset$ and so is $\cap G_n$ since $\cap \bar V_n\subset \cap G_n$